# Persistent Session State using SQLServer

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, session, session-variables

This is a bit of a general and multifaceted question.. so here it goes...

I know that it is possible to have a persistent session state and to have sql server handle it.
so what I would like to do is use this, but every time the user logs in (i am using form authentication)i want them to get their old session back.
i would like to do this so i can store lots of user information in there including things like module permissions (for a site i am developing) and maybe even some customization variable too?

I would also like to know if an administrator can then go on and modify another users session variable too so i can use the session state to administer services also!

how would i go about implementing these things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't how standard SQL Session State works; you would need to implement a custom solution. I guess it depends on how much 'session' information there is per-user, and what types are involved.

If you're already using the database to store user credentials (which it sounds like you are), it would be relatively easy to add a session table called 'UserState' or something similar, which tracks all the values you want to tie to a user. You may need to add more tables to suit your requirements, for example if you store multiple instances of a particular session state item for a user.

Comment: Maybe it would be possible when the user logs in the will copy his whole "session template"  to his new session id table?

Comment: This would be faster then moving it over one at a time into his new session using asp to do it wouldnt it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. Session template ? If he wants to persist session state into a database table, it stands to reason that to restore state when a user logs in, it's going to be loaded from the database. No ?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i want.... to restore the user session every time they log in...will this be done automatically?

Comment: No - you will have to write a custom solution for this.